# Can I pass Audio/Video object from expo-av into redux state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, expo

I want to have a global Audio/Video object in my react-native application. I have a player and I want to manipulate music player in every side of my application. But I correctly dont know how I can create a global Audio/Video object and use functions like play/pause/setNewSong globally from different components. And my question is can I create redux store and pass audio object into store? Or maybe I must do it in another way. Thank you for answers

Comment: How about storing the filenames instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Don't put non-serializable values like class instances into the Redux store](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#do-not-put-non-serializable-values-in-state-or-actions).

You should probably keep this near the root of your React component tree and make it accessible to the rest of the app using React's Context API.

Comment: I have thought about that, thank you. I think you help me with my problem